# For real numbers $x$ and $y$ , find the minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, contest-math, radicals

Thailand International Math Olympiad 2018 secondary senior problem 18

> For real numbers $x$ and $y$ , find the minimum value of $$ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2} $$

This question was under geometry. I found this really challenging. I couldn't see any geometry other than circle equations in this problem.

Comment: Doesn't that have an obvious geometric interpretation?

Comment: It’s painfully obvious but that’s the distance of a point to $(0,0)$ plus distance to $(3,4)$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the formulas seem similar to the distance formula in $\mathbb R^2$. In fact, the formula is the sum of the distances of point $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$ and $(3,4)$. We know that any point on the segment in between $(0,0)$ and $(3,4)$ will minimize the function by the triangle inequality. In particular, $(0,0)$ will.

So, we simply evaluate $$\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$$To get our answer of $5$.

Comment: Also quote triangle inequality and this proof is rigorous

Answer (score 4):

Since it is a **senior secondary** problem one may surely use the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality):

We have

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(3-x)^2+(4-y)^2}$$ $$\stackrel{Minkowski}{\geq} \sqrt{(3-x+x)^2 + (4-y+y)^2}=\sqrt{25}=5.$$

Equality is achieved for $\binom xy = \lambda \binom{3-x}{4-y}$, for $\lambda \geq 0$ or $\binom{3-x}{4-y}=\binom 00$. So, the lower bound is attained, for example, for $x=3, y=4$.

Comment: I think you mean $\sqrt{25}$

Comment: @DonThousand Exactly. :-) Thanks Don.

Comment: Also I think you meant $4-y+y$ after applying Minkowski

Comment: Also, Minkowski has equality whenever one vector is a scalar multiple of the other so there are other solutions than $(\frac32,2)$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Concerning the $x$-$y$ thing you are right. It was an obvious typo you could have quickly edited. Concerning the equality you are NOT completely right. Please, refer to the link I provided. We have $\binom xy = \lambda \binom{3-x}{4-y}$ for $\color{blue}{\lambda \geq 0}$ or $\binom{3-x}{4-y} = \binom 00$. And regarding the question it was not necessary to find all cases when equality holds but only to show that the lower bound is attained.

Comment: @trancelocation Thank you for the response- I am aware of the fact you mentioned (I forgot to type out "positively linearly dependent"). I thought that you might mention that every point in the convex hull of $(0,0)$ and $(3,4)$ is a minimizer. Great answer btw